# How to serve sourceMappingURL files?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, minify, minimize

Currently I am serving sourceMappingURL files with following contenttype:

```
Content-type:text/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

Is this correct? It works, but I don't know, if it is correct. What other headers should I send along with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript sourcemaps should be served with `Conent-type: application/json` since the file is single  JSON object.

To supply source map over HTTP, use `SourceMap: <url>` header.

Or you can link source map in file comment for both, javascript (`//# sourceMappingURL=<url>`) and css (`/*# sourceMappingURL=<url> */`).

Note: `X-SourceMap <url>` is deprecated.

Source: [Source Map Revision 3 Proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit#)

Comment: This does not answer my question. When I download for instance jquery with bower sourceMappingURL is already there. I will not change that. I wrote my own middleware in node to serve them. Which content-type or mimetype should I give them?

Comment: Sorry, improved my answer.